# Apache POI update workbooks with linked sheet references

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to make a workbook update before I open it. It has a linked sheet reference.

I have 2 separate workbooks.

`Sheet 1 workbook 1 has a cell that references Sheet 1 workbook 2.`

After looking at the docs and forums I found `FormulaEvaluator.setupReferencedWorkbooks`
My question is how to set this up and get it to work. I made a class called ExcelReader that holds the open workbook and formulaEvaluator for that object. I then made a `HashMap<String,FormulaEvaluator>` and did

```
map.put("Book1.xlsx",wb1.formulaEvaluator);
map.put("Book2.xlsx"...);
```

Then did:

```
FormulaEvaluator eval = new FormulaEvaluator() {
}
```

Added unimplemented methods. 
Then did

```
eval.setupReferencedWorkbooks();

eval.evaluateAll();
```

But it doesn't update. Any ideas?

Comment: I even tried doing `workbook1.evaluator.setupReferencedWorkbooks(map);` `workbook1.evaluator.evaluate( cell A1 );` and I get the error: `could not resolve external workbook name 'Book2.xlsx'. Workbook environment has not been set up` However I have a readExcel object for both workbooks and both have a workBook and a formulaEvaluator for the workbook

Comment: Your code shows only a link for `fileNameWorkBook1`, but the exception says you're missing `Book2.xlsx` - what happens if you put that open workbook onto the map too?

Comment: @gagravarr sorry didn't mean to write it like that. I put both workbooks in the map Book1 and Book2 so Book2 is in the map but t sill doesn't find an open workbook for it.

Comment: Hang on a minute, why are you creating your own FormulaEvaluator implementation and implementing methods? That could be your problem. You need to use the Apache POI provided evaluator, not your own!

Comment: @gagravarr well I needed to use a formula evaluator so I did new FormulaEvaluator and that made me add unimplemented methods. How do I just use the Apache POI provided evaluator? I even tried calling the setupReferencedWorkbooks on the evaluator of one of the readExcel object and it gave that error still

Comment: `FormulaEvaluator` is an interface, as the javadocs make quite clear, so you shouldn't be doing a new on it! You need to ask the [CreationHelper](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CreationHelper.html) you get from the Workbook object to make one for you